# Using AQuery (or other) to clone RelativeView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-query

From what I've seen, AQuery is pretty much a jQuery for Android programming in Java. I'm a web programmer, so I'm used to jQuery, which is easy to use, so I want to do the same to manipulate the layout of my app.

My question: is there an easy way (preferably with AQuery, but not necessary) to clone a `View` and all it's children and then insert it somewhere in the layout? I've read something about inflating, but there is no actual full example that contains how to put the inflated View in the layout (or maybe I'm missing something).

Comment: [droidQuery](http://phil-brown.github.io/droidQuery/) may be easier for you as a web developer (for changing UI and performing Ajax requests), since its syntax is designed to be as close to *jQuery* as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on this, I've ended up not using any framework, but the layout inflater, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9851602/when-inflating-a-layout-xml-dynamically-multiple-times-how-can-i-differentiate).