# ActionBar is re-created always

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-configchanges

I have created the action bar and tabs like in my previous post,

[Fragment webview java script function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077002/fragment-webview-java-script-function-is-not-working/)

[Menu in Action bar Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16028911/menu-in-action-bar-android/).

I have loaded the webview in the ActionBar. In the webview I have place a button for capturing the image and the **device's camera is opened and take the picture** then I have returned the values to the loaded html file. I have **checked the values in the html file from the native method, that is fine**. But the **action bar is recreated always**. Instead of the open the camera and return the values to the webview, If I am trying to **send the any string to the html file it's not reloaded**. If I am start any activity inside the action bar tab scenario only the onCreate() method called twice, so the html page is reloaded. I have specified the **"android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"** for the all the activities. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Hi, any suggestion for this..

Answer (score 0):

If we give all the **configChanges** attributes in **AndroidManifest.xml** file, the activity which is started is **not recreated** always. But in the target device, we have to check **"Settings-->Developer Options-->Apps-->Don't keep activities"** this checkbox **must not checked**. If we enable this checkbox, the started activity is **destroyed as soon as the user leaves the activity**. This option should not be checked, then only the started activity is not recreated always.

**Note :** I have checked this in **Google Nexus S 4.1.2** Android device.